# AndEngine Design Graphics Assets

Tags: android, andengine, game-development

I plan to develop a small game. I want to ask my graphics designer to design the game scene but currently I do not know which resolution to choose.

I have been readed many posts regarding this issue, I understood that if I choose the RationResolutionPolicy I can start the design in photoshop or illustrator for 800x480 size and then the engine will scale the rest.

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AndEngine will actually adjust the resolution via `RatioResolutionPolicy`. Basically you really just want the resolution to be nice and big and for the device you plan to release on.

I made a game for my Galaxy S3 which has a resolution of 1280x720. So if I deploy my game on another phone with lesser resolution AndEngine will adjust it automatically.

Remember one thing, if your game resolution is 1280x720 and your devices resolution is greater (for example 1920x1080) the game will stretch and distort.

Comment: Pay attention that it's good to detect screen ratio and use more than one resolution according to the detected ratio

Comment: Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820219/andengine-sprites-are-not-getting-scaled-on-different-devices