# AndEngine - Sprites are not getting scaled on different devices

Tags: android, andengine, resolution, android-resolution

Code :

This is how m initializing camera.
I', trying to get resolution of device and based on that i set camera width and height.

```
     public class GameActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

        private SmoothCamera mCamera;
        private DisplayMetrics dM; 

        private int CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT;

        private double  ScreenWidth,
                        ScreenHeight,
                        resolutionRatio;


        public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

             //set Camera
            getDeviceResolution();
            setCamera();


        EngineOptions options =  new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, 
            new RatioResolutionPolicy((int)this.getCameraWidth(),(int)this.getCameraHeight()),
            //new FillResolutionPolicy(),
            mCamera);
          return options;

        }

      private void getDeviceResolution() {
            dM = new DisplayMetrics();
            this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dM);
            this.ScreenWidth    = dM.widthPixels;
            this.ScreenHeight   = dM.heightPixels;
            this.resolutionRatio = this.ScreenWidth/this.ScreenHeight;

                resolutionRatio = (double)Math.round(resolutionRatio * 100) / 100;

            Log.d("Resolution","ScrennWidth: "+this.ScreenWidth );
            Log.d("Resolution","ScrennHeight: "+this.ScreenHeight );
                    Log.d("Resolution","Resolution Ratio: " +   this.resolutionRatio );
        }



    private void setCamera() {

        if(resolutionRatio == 1.66){
            this.setCameraHeight(340);
            this.setCameraWidth(400);
        }else if(resolutionRatio == 2.13){
            this.setCameraHeight(480);
            this.setCameraWidth(1024);
        }else if(resolutionRatio == 1.77){
            this.setCameraHeight(720);
            this.setCameraWidth(1280);
        }else if(resolutionRatio == 1.5){
            this.setCameraHeight(320);
            this.setCameraWidth(480);
        }else if(resolutionRatio == 1.67){
            this.setCameraHeight(480);
            this.setCameraWidth(800);
        }else {
            this.setCameraHeight((int) this.ScreenHeight);
            this.setCameraWidth((int) this.ScreenWidth);
        }

        // Create a Camera
        this.mCamera = new SmoothCamera(0,0,(int)getCameraWidth(),(int)getCameraHeight(),100,100,1.0f);
            mCamera.setZoomFactor(1.0f);

            mCamera.setBoundsEnabled(true);
            mCamera.setBounds(0, 0, mCamera.getWidth(), mCamera.getHeight());   
        }



        }
```

The issue is.

I've etried game on device with resolution 480x320;
[image]

and when i tried same code on device with resolution 800X480[image]

I Thinks sprites are not getting scaled on higher resolution devices.
As per my knowledge andengine scales camera and sprites natively.

So why sprites are not getting scaled on this situation?

What should i do to scale up sprites based on resolution?

I tried FillResolutionPolicy too. Same thing.

I'm using TexturePackerExtension of andengine adn SpriteSheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a `Camera` with a fixed `width` and a `height` that is calculated by the devices screen aspectratio. Pair that with a `FillResolutionPolicy` and you get what you want.

Note:

> AndEngine doesn't *scale* `Sprites` for you, but you set the `Camera` so that the whole `Scene` appears scaled.

Answer (score 2):

AndEngine does scale your `Sprites` even in your example. The reason why the result is not what you expected is that you set the camera's `width`and `height` manually (based on the resolution).

If you really want every sprite scaled in the same way on every display, then you should choose **one** fixed resolution in which you create your game. 
For example you could set up every sprite and every position to a resolution of 960x640.

```
 // skip the whole if(resolutionRatio == 1.66){..  part
this.mCamera = new SmoothCamera(0, 0, 960f, 640f, 100, 100, 1.0f);
```

AndEngine will then scale the camera, so that it fills as much of the display as possible.

```
 public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
      EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR, new RatioResolutionPolicy(1.5f), camera;
      return options;
 }
```

the `1.5f` is the fitting aspect ratio for the 960x640 resolution. 
Now you won't have to take care of the different display sizes anymore.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem. i got white strips on left and right side of the camera when tried on different devices with different resolution ratio.

Comment: Those stripes are normal, AndEngine tries to fill the most part of the display without stretching the images (by keeping the fixed aspect ratio). Anyway, if you want to use different resolutions (like you do in your example by detecting the display metrics...) you need to scale your Sprites manually. In your 800x480 example the cards appear smaller than in the 480x320 example, because the camera is bigger, but the cards kept their original size. But if you don't want to scale and position every single sprite, use one fixed camera size and let AndEngine do the rest.

Comment: Also - since white stripes are usually undesirable, you can change them to any color you choose, such as black, using the Theme attribute of your Application. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779679/setting-android-theme-background-color.
Changing your ratioResolutionPolicy will also get rid of the bars but depending on your layout can cause other display problems since some of the screen visible on one device is not visible on another.